# generate key hash for android to use in facebook

Tags: android

when i use this command in windows  keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64     to get android hash this message appear   'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Try it programmatically as noted in [Getting Started Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started):

```
public void generateFBKeyHash(Context mContext) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "YOUR PACKAGE NAME IN YOUR MANIFEST",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.e("fb key hash", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("failed", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Note**: Ensure you have the meta-data in your manifest

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Comment: i will use it in ionic2

Comment: Hmm, I'm unsure of ionic. I would edit your question to note that you're using ionic. if it doesn't work, I'll delete the answer.